# How to fix error saving data to database with hibernate to mssql

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, apache-poi

very new to Java/Spring/Hibernate stack. I can't get the data extracted from and xlsx sheet using the apache poi to save to an mssql database. Using an in memory database, Derby, this all just works fine which leads me to believe that it has some thing to do with the data being mapped between the java class and the mssql database table.

DB:

```
CREATE TABLE BASICS.IncomingData.BulkRefundUpload (
      id int PRIMARY KEY,
      daxPaymentReference varchar(255),
      amount float,
      refundReason varchar(255),
      invoiceId varchar(255),
      processingStatus varchar(255),
      retryCount int,
      iglobisRequest varchar(255),
      iglobisResponse varchar(255),
      refundStatus varchar(255),
      createDateTime date,
      createdBy varchar(255),
      updateDateTime date,
      modifiedBy varchar(255)
)
```

Class:

```
// omitted imports

@Entity
@Table(name = "IncomingData.BulkRefundUpload")
public class Refund {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String daxPaymentReference;

    @Column
    private double amount;

    @Column
    private String refundReason;

    @Column
    private String invoiceId;

    @Column
    private String processingStatus;

    @Column
    private int retryCount;

    @Column
    private String iglobisRequest;

    @Column
    private String iglobisResponse;

    @Column
    private String refundStatus;

    @Column
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date createDateTime;

    @Column
    private String createdBy;

    @Column
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date updateDateTime;

    @Column
    private String modifiedBy;

    // no arg constructor
    public Refund() {}

    // regular constructor
    public Refund(String daxPaymentReference, double amount, String refundReason, String invoiceId, String processingStatus, int retryCount, String iglobisRequest, String iglobisResponse, String refundStatus, String createdBy, String modifiedBy) {
        super();
        this.daxPaymentReference = daxPaymentReference;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.refundReason = refundReason;
        this.invoiceId = invoiceId;
        this.processingStatus = processingStatus;
        this.retryCount = retryCount;
        this.iglobisRequest = iglobisRequest;
        this.iglobisResponse = iglobisResponse;
        this.refundStatus = refundStatus;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    // getters and setters omitted
}
```

And the method trying to write the data, it iterates through rows in an xlsx:

```
List<Refund> refunds = new ArrayList<>();

            sheet.rowIterator().forEachRemaining(row -> {

                if(row.getRowNum() != 0) {

                    refunds.add(new Refund(
                            row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue(), //daxPaymentReference
                            row.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue(), //amount
                            row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue(), //refundReason
                            "",
                            "new",
                            0,
                            "",
                            "",
                            "",
                            "defaultCreatedByUser",
                            ""
                    ));
                }
            });
```

And finally the error:

```
Hibernate: select next value for hibernate_sequence
2019-01-23 13:58:04.260  WARN 1544 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 102, SQLState: S0001
2019-01-23 13:58:04.260 ERROR 1544 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Incorrect syntax near 'hibernate_sequence'.
2019-01-23 13:58:04.315 ERROR 1544 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'hibernate_sequence'.
```

Adding image from debugger showing the values being added to the refund object:
[image]

Comment: Try to debug values, which passed to "Refund" object.

Comment: also the upper case for the table definition? did you check the created table? which value do you have in you mysql lower_case_table_names property?

Comment: @SlavaMurygin Yeah, I did this, and the values appear to match as far as I can tell. Two secs and I will add a picture of the values with debugger to original post.

Comment: @BryanAcuñaNúñez Honestly, I didn't really follow what you were saying... and it is mssql not mysql

Comment: The only difference I see is that in my Java class i have `private double amount` which is mapped to `amount float,` in my table... but my understanding was that this is correct to do so.

Comment: OK. You have a SQL Server error: "Incorrect syntax near 'hibernate_sequence'", which means hibernate produces bad statement. Most probably you have a hibernate error, which is sent to SQL Server as a command.
You have to debug hibernate log to see what it sends to SQL Server. Then you might have better idea where the problem is.

Comment: Take a look at the line "@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)" 
You might need to replace "AUTO" by "IDENTITY".

Comment: So looking at the logs, here is more info. SQL query creates DB as `BASICS.IncomingData.BulkRefundUpload`. All the tables in BASICS Db are `IncomingData.<tablename>`. In Refund class, I have `@Table(name = "IncomingData.BulkRefundUpload")` and log is showing the following error: `sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'incoming_data_bulk_refund_upload'.`

It's almost like Hibernate can't seem to find the table it should be writing to.

Comment: I think you do not have hibernate_sequence in your databse.